# How do you build Soul Meter?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

Correct me if the name of this meter is wrong; I am referring to the curved one at the edge of your health bar, that has the number 0, 1, or 2, depending on how full it is.

I know that this generally just goes up through the course of play, and it goes up quickly enough that casual players don't really need to think about how exactly they're building the meter. However, depending on how the meter builds, this could make strategies focused around that, like strategies focused around breaking armor in Soul Calibur IV.

What actions build up your meter, and how much do they build it up? Do some attacks build it up more than others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [a sticky on 8WayRun](http://8wayrun.com/threads/new-scv-critical-gauge-meter-information-and-discussion.8273/) (popular fighting forums for all things Soul Calibur related):

> Building the Meter:
>
> **Good meter build**: Landing hits and counter-hits
>
> **Moderate meter build**: Just-guard, ukemi, landing blocked attacks, guarding attacks, breaking throw (little meter gain).
>
> **Things that build random or uncertain amount of meter**: Taking damage, getting up from ground, low hits (debatable), whiffing attack.
>   Whiffing certain attacks however don't build meter. Weird.
>
> **ZERO meter build**: Throws - They build no meter for anyone (thrower or player being thrown). Breaking a throw, however, builds a little
>   meter as stated above since you now take a bit of damage from breaking
>   a throw.
>
> **After your opponent has won TWO rounds**: If your opponent wins two rounds, you begin the new round with +100% meter (ex: if you had 25%
>   meter, you now have 125%). You notice this from the character's super
>   saiyan power-up visual at the beginning of the round. Comeback
>   mechanic!

Comment: Do critical edge moves and brave edge moves return any meter if they connect, or is it all negative? Does getting hit with a critical edge build your meter?